# creating dict of dicts: looping

Tags: python

I wanted to create a dictionary of dictionaries (DofD) using a loop. Inside the loop, my 'subdict' variable would get set and then added with a new name to the DofD.

I read from a file, split the contents into blocks based on a delimiter, "####", that separates what I want in each sub-dict. I name each entry in the DofD based on one of the fields within the block.

I was confused because my output DofD had properly named entries, but all the information across the subdicts was identical. All values reflected the last sub-dict's content.

```
idxs=[i for i,val in enumerate(fileContents) if val=='####\r\n']
paramsDict={}
for i in range(len(idxs)):
    pos=idxs[i]
    if i < len(idxs)-1: endLine=idxs[i+1]+1 # watch out for end of file
    else: endLine=len(fileContents)
    blockForSubDict=fileContents[idxs[i]+1:endLine]

    paramsDict[blockForSubDict[0].split()[0]]={'Name': blockForSubDict[0].split()[0], 'Values' : [float(x.replace('\r\n','')) for x in blockForSubDict[5:lenBlock]]}
```

I worked out an example by hand to create a dictionary of dictionaries to make sure I wasn't doing something odd with my syntax:

```
d1={'Name': 'name1', 'Value': 30}

d2={'Name': 'name2', 'Value': 29}

d3={}
d3[d1['Name']]=d1
d3[d2['Name']]=d2 

d3
```

> {'name1': {'Name': 'name1', 'Value': 30},
>   'name2': {'Name': 'name2', 'Value': 29}}

This worked.

What have I messed up in the loop?

Comment: This isn't a question - you should change it to actually be a question, then [answer it yourself](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: converted to a question format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was that the entries in my DofD are really just references to the subdict in my loop. This meant that my DofD just had a bunch of differently named entries that all point to the same subdict. The content of the subdict changed with each iteration and ultimately reflected the block value of the last time through my loop. Therefore all of the entries in my DofD showed this same set of subdict values.

Rather than make a differently named subdict on each iteration, I decided to go with a deepcopy() of the subdict into the DofD so that each entry maintained its unique content.

My code now looks something like:

```
    import copy
    ...
    paramsDict[blockForSubDict[0].split()[0]]={'Name':
    copy.deepcopy(blockForSubDict[0].split()[0]), 
    'Values' : 
    [copy.deepcopy(float(x.replace('\r\n',''))) for x in blockForSubDict[5:lenBlock]]}
```